# Possible Encoding issue with Ampersands

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sharepoint, encoding

Sometimes when we're generating a URL the following string is used in place of the ampersand - `%c2%a4cy`.

I've not seen this type of encoding before and I can't work out where it's coming from. We're generating the URL using a `StringBuilder` in an MVC app. The URL is then being stored in an HTML field within SharePoint.

Answer (score 2):

I have had this problem before. If grabbing the url from your view try this:

@Html.Raw(ViewBag.Url)

Obviously replace ViewBag.Url with where your url is stored.

Hope that helps!